# Entity Framework 6.x issue with MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, mysql-connector

I am creating Web API using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and MySQL server. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio connector 1.2.6 to connect the DB.
I am getting error in such a way that I am not able to add model.edmx file into my project. Please find the error snapshot in the link - [Entity Framework 6.x error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wTB.png).

I tried to downgrade the Entity-framework but not able to resolve the issue.

I also tried the workaround mentioned in the below links: 
http://www.cnblogs.com/dupeng0811/p/solve-your-project-references-latest.html
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/445
http://qursaan-howto.blogspot.in/2014/07/solve-your-project-references-latest.html

But still I am not able to solve this issue. It'd be great if someone can help me on how to troubleshoot/workaround this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in that same configuration ;)
Install nu-get packets in following sequence:

1. EntityFramework 6.1.3 and rebuild project
2. MySQL.Data 6.9.9
3. MySQL.Data.Entity 6.9.9 (**important! install "Data.Entity" by Oracle**, not "Data.EntitIES" by MySQL)
4. MySQL.WEB 6.9.9

It should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can please check your web.config. It should have entries for mysql provider and mysql db provider factory. Something like this (it should be done automatically when you install MySql.Data.Entity package from nuget):

```
      ...
      <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <providers>
         <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
         <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.data>
          <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
              <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
          </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
      ...
```